# Executing and reading the response from a command line application using python

Tags: python, windows, console-application, command-prompt

I am having a windows console application for my tool. I need to execute commands like login, connect e.tc and need to read the response. How can I do this with python. I am using python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `os` in linux, it is recommended to use `subprocess` for windows.

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output("dir C:", shell=True)
```